# Getting rows from database but printing each one of them where I want

Tags: php, html, database

I have a number of rows I want to retrieve from the database but I want to print each row in the exact place I want and only even rows.
Is this possible? If yes, how can I achieve it?

```
<?php 
$sql="Select * from plays where usertype=2 and idgame=$idgame";
$result=mysqli_query($link, $sql);

while($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$aword = $row['word'];
} ?>

<body>
 <div id="row">
      <span class="attemp">1 :</span>
      <span class="word"><?php print  //I want to print here only the 2nd fetched row  ?></span>
  </div>

 <div id="row">
      <span class="attemp">2 :</span>
      <span class="word"><?php print  //I want to print here only the 4th fetched row  ?></span>
  </div>  
</body>
```

Comment: Do you need the odd rows to print somewhere else, or not at all? And just to be sure, you do mean rows and not columns, right? (No offense meant, some people accidentally say rows when they ask.)

Comment: within the while loop declare an array and push all rows in that array like this, wordArray[] = $row['word'], now you have an array with all rows in it, in the HTML now, print wordArray[1] and wordArray[3], or any other  elements you need by accessing them using array[index], let us know if this helps

Comment: Look into [`fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).

Answer (score 0):

If when retrieving the data, you store it into an array, you can then output the data as you need to (remembering that arrays are 0 based)...

```
$aword = [];
while($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $aword[] = $row['word'];
} ?>

<body>
 <div id="row">
      <span class="attemp">1 :</span>
      <span class="word"><?php echo $aword[1];  ?></span>
  </div>

 <div id="row">
      <span class="attemp">2 :</span>
      <span class="word"><?php echo $aword[3];  ?></span>
  </div>  
</body>
```

Also I would suggest that if you only want the one column from the data, then select just that column rather than `*`...

```
$sql="Select word from plays where usertype=2 and idgame=".(int)$idgame;
```

and the obligatory comment about using prepared statements to stop SQL injection and some common errors.

Comment: Although it should work, I believe that using `mysqli_fetch_all` would be cleaner and faster.

Comment: *"and the obligatory comment about using prepared statements to stop SQL injection and some common errors."* - Seeing that `$idgame` is an integer, a simple `(int)` would suffice. Yet, a prepared statement is always best.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I tried it and it prints the letters on that index of all the rows. Example: if there are two  words in the database like, "fish" and "spoon", when I  echo $aword [2], the print shows  "s" and "o".

Comment: Are you sue you have `$aword[]` in the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "Select * from plays where usertype=2 and idgame=$idgame";
$result = mysqli_query(isConnect(),$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
     {
       echo "$row[0]";
      }
     ?>
```

Comment: $row[0] is 1st column of your table or you can use $row['column name']

Comment: You have to fully explain your answer. As it is currently written, it has severe formatting or content problems. It is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed